# Spring Web-mvc not working with Spring Boot[Spring cloud]

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot, microservices

I am new to microservices.I have created a microservice application using Spring.I am using "**spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server**".I have total 3 modules:

- microservicecldm
- account-microservice
- webclient-microservice-server

Find below their main classes accordingly:

```
 @EnableEurekaServer
 @SpringBootApplication
 public class MicroservicecldmApplication {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(MicroservicecldmApplication.class, args);
       }
 }

   @EnableDiscoveryClient
   @SpringBootApplication
   @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.wmsdm.cloud")
   public class WebclientMicroserviceServerApplication{ 
        public static void main(String[] args) {
             SpringApplication.run(WebclientMicroserviceServerApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

In application.properties I have following entries:

```
spring.application.name=WebclientMicroserviceServerApplication
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone:http://localhost:9091/eureka/
server.port=9993
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=80
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

I have a AccountController class as follows:

```
@Controller
public class AccountController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/account", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewAccount() {
        return "accountSummary";
    }
 }
```

I have the accountSummary.jsp page in my `/WEB-INF/view` path.Also in maven's pom.xml I have the following dependencies along with other dependencies:

```
   <groupId>com.wmsdm.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>webclient-microservice-server</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>

   <name>webclient-microservice-server</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>

   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
      <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
              <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
              <type>pom</type>
              <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
```

Inspite of these when I hit the URL:

```
http://localhost:9993/WebclientMicroserviceServerApplication/account
```

I get the error `No mapping found for the requested uri`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `spring-boot-starter-web` instead of `tomcat-embed-jasper`. You can use multiple starters in your `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

See [spring.io](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) for more info.

Comment: added the entire pom.xml for web module

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the context component scan base package is correct. If not specified specify it using regex.

Comment: @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.wmsdm.cloud") is allready added as I have posted.Moreover all the classes is under same package.So,as per spring boot  @SpringBootApplication annotation  will scan.@Arun

Comment: its not the problem with eureka or any Netflix tools. Its the problem with spring not able to find the `@component`s or any annotations

Comment: when the internal tomcat is getting up I found that it has scanned the @RequestMapping("/account").I saw the info message in eclipse console
@Arun

Comment: What is the URL mapping of n `WebAppInitializer`?